# Calculate Percent Of Patients With (Some Metric) By Site in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerpivot

Briefly, I am trying to compute a "percent of patients with (some metric) by site" from two related tables, Patient and PatientMetric, using a custom measure in Power BI.  I have a solution using Power Pivot in Excel, but the same measure formula is not working with Power BI.

The tables are:

```
Patient, with columns SiteCode and PatientCode
PatientMetric, with columns PatientCode and MetricCode
```

The two tables are related in the obvious way:

```
PatientMetric.PatientCode -> Patient.PatientCode
```

I've included sample data below.

In Power Pivot, I create a custom measure ...

```
DISTINCTCOUNT(PatientMetric[PatientCode])/DISTINCTCOUNT([PatientCode])
```

... and when I create a pivot table with Rows = "SiteCode" (from Patient), Columns = "MetricCode" (from PatientMetric), and Values = (my custom measure), I get what I was hoping to get ...

```
SiteCode  M1    M2
1         67%   67%
2         100%  50%
```

In Excel, the denominator in the measure is properly filtered by the SiteCode before counting.

However, when I use Power BI, with exactly the same data model and relationships, and build a table, I get the results ...

```
SiteCode  M1    M2
1         40%   40%
2         40%   20%
```

... because Power BI is using the total patient count as the denominator, unfiltered by the SiteCode.

How can I fix this?

Patient data is ...

```
+----------+-------------+
| SiteCode | PatientCode |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 |          10 |
|        1 |          11 |
|        1 |          12 |
|        2 |          20 |
|        2 |          21 |
+----------+-------------+
```

... and PatientMetric data is ...

```
+-------------+------------+
| PatientCode | MetricCode |
+-------------+------------+
| 10          | M1         |
| 10          | M2         |
| 11          | M1         |
| 12          | M2         |
| 20          | M1         |
| 20          | M2         |
| 21          | M1         |
+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Assuming you specify the table name in the denominator as `Patient[PatientCode]`, I'm getting the result you're looking for. I'm unable to reproduce the results you say you're getting.

Comment: @AlexisOlson, thanks for taking the time to look into thing.  After reading your response, I decided to start over and rebuild my Power BI slicers and table and it worked fine.  I must have had some setting wrong somewhere (though I couldn't find it).  Sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't "solve" the problem per se, but after wasting @AlexisOlson's time, I recreated my Power BI slicer and table and got the correct results.  I compared the working version to the non-working version and couldn't find the difference, but there are LOTS of settings.

Moral of the story is: try recreating with a stripped down version; Power BI has lots of hidden stuff that can bit you.